# DoS attack blocks website while in another connections show website run normally

Tags: denial-of-service

I am learning Ethical Hacking.
I create my own website on a cloud hosting service for testing purposes.

I run [DoS attack](https://github.com/cyweb/hammer) from my local VM and it shows that website is down.

When I sent a link to my friend he told me that the website runs normally. When I change network and connect to another WiFi it really shows that website is running normally.

What is the point here? What do I need to be focused on?

Comment: What tools did you use?what were you hoping to achive?how much resource does the server have?

Comment: I am using hammer tools which is open-source tools. I am hoping to down website using that tools in way to learn how does DoS and DDoS works. Currently I am using Linux Kali with 4GB of RAM memory and 2 CPU's.

Comment: Where is this website? Is it on a VM, too? Change network? What does that mean? When dealing with network level issues it is important to describe the ***network***.

Comment: What kind of DOS are you performing?Exhaustion of resources or vulnerability related DOS?

Comment: @DobroSumljivMomak: looks like a tool which exhausts the resources on the local machine faster than the resources on the target website - at least for some sane server setup. And since you are running it from your own machine it is not distributed either. The "website is down" claim might actually be more a lack of resources on your attackers machine. Oh, and the tool does not even do proper HTTP. Looks like crap to me.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, I also see that tool doesn't do proper HTTP since website is still running. This tools is peac of nothing. 
I am not sure do I need to change Network adapter since I am using TP-LINK TL-WR522N USB WiFi Adapter ?

Comment: You are not going to create enough traffic from a single VM to bring down a site hosted on a cloud server. You are more likely to DoS your local machine or your home router.

Comment: The code of hammer suggests that it is supposed to be run from many bots. You are not going to have an effect with just a single machine (with limited resources)

Comment: The first thing you lean in _ethical_ hacking is that you should not attack systems without their owner's consent (including not (D)DoSing hosting providers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that you attacked a hosting provider. The first thing you lean in ethical hacking is that you should not attack systems without the consent of the owner and of the service provider. This includes not (D)DoSing Internet hosting providers.

Anyway, the most likely explanation in your case is that the hosting provider answers your attempted DoS with a static page, which for him requires almost as much effort as blacklisting you at network level.